# interested in zeroMQ but client binding options prove limiting

Tags: actionscript-3, rabbitmq, middleware, stomp, zeromq

This is related to an earlier question I had asked about what sort of middleware one can use for developing a client/server app.

Among the options suggested, I was intrigued by zeroMQ and its capabilities.

Since morning, I have been researching on using zeroMQ for my application. However, since my client is a Adobe AIR/FLEX, I see a steep curve in using zeroMQ since there are no bindings available for actionscript.

Google search shows a popular client called STOMP that can be used for messaging in flex based applications but there doesn't seem to be any STOMP adapter for zeroMQ either.

This leaves me with other alternatives such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ (since they both seem to have STOMP adapters) as possible middleware choices.

How hard/easy it is to develop to stomp adapter for zeroMQ? I hardly found any documentation on writing an adapter. Or is it worth writing an adapter for zeroMQ than focus on, say, using RabbitMQ that supports STOMP.

Finally, what are other popular alternatives to STOMP for Flex on the client side and leverage zeroMQ on the middleware part.

Thanks
Dece

Answer (score 1):

STOMP is probably going to be the only option from FLEX since it's by far the simplest MOM protocol available.  Furthermore, since it's such a simple protocol, I'm surprised someone has not yet implemented a bridge from STOMP to zeromq.